# How to use string pattern while creating S3 Batch operation manifest file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have tens of thousands of objects in my S3 bucket. And I want to encrypt all the existing objects using a KMS key. With my research, I could see `S3 Batch Operations` does this in single request.

My existing files in my S3 bucket are following a pattern. Lets assume `sample_file_*.log`. How to use such pattern in my manifest file?

Sample Manifest File (csv):

```
<source_bucket_name>,objectName1
<source_bucket_name>,objectName2
<source_bucket_name>,*.log
```

When I tried the Batch job with the above manifest file, it throws me `Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: XYZ123; S3 Extended Request ID: xyz123; Proxy: null)` error.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

S3 Batch Operations does not work that way. You have to provide the key explicitly. If you have numerous S3 objects in a bucket, you can make use of S3 Inventory to collect all keys.

Answer (score 0):

As of re:Invent 2023, you can now use S3 Batch Operations this way! With a generated manifest and specified Prefix/Suffix you can filter your bucket down to the matching list of objects and apply the encryption to the matching items.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/batch-ops-create-job.html for more details